# Categorizing mysql data into seperate html tables?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

I have a database query that returns ItemID, ItemName, CategoryID and CategoryName. I am trying to group my results into separate html tables by their CategoryName so the end result looks something like this:

```
 ________________________________
|____________CategoryName________|
| ItemName |                     |
|__________|                     |
| ItemName |                     |
|__________|                     |
| ItemName |                     |
|__________|_____________________|
 ________________________________
|____________CategoryName________|
| ItemName |                     |
|__________|                     |
| ItemName |                     |
|__________|                     |
| ItemName |                     |
|__________|_____________________|
```

Currently I can output my data into one table, but I am uncertain how to go about the rest.
Seems i have better ascii art skills than php skills :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML is off, but this should get you started:

```
<?php

$query = 'SELECT CategoryID, CategoryName, ItemID, ItemName
FROM tableName
ORDER BY CategoryID';

$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result || mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "No rows found";
    exit;
}

$lastCatID = 0; //or some other invalid category ID

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if($lastCatID != $row['CategoryID']) {
        //starting a new category
        if($lastCatID != 0) {
            //close up previous table
            echo '</table>';
        }

        //start a new table
        echo '<table><th><td colspan="2">Category '
                . $row['CategoryName'] .'</td></th>';
        $lastCatID = $row['CategoryID'];
    }

    echo '<tr><td>' . $row['ItemName'] . '</td><td></td></tr>';
}

if($lastCatID != 0) {
    //close up the final table
    echo '</table>';
}

mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

Comment: This does exactly what I wanted to do! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sort your data by CategoryName and then start loop. In loop, write starting HTML for first table and start outputing row by row, but before each row check for CategoryName - if it's changed, then close current table and start new one.

Answer (score 0):

I like working with `foreach` better - like so:

```
$query = "SELECT CategoryID, CategoryName, ItemID, ItemName
FROM tableName
ORDER BY CategoryID";

$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result || mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo "No rows found";
    exit;
}

$rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

// create an array with the data structure closest to the HTML 
foreach( $rows as $row){
    $cats_data[$row['CategoryID']]['CategoryName'] = $row['categoryName'] ;
    $cats_data[$row['CategoryID']]['Items'][] = $row['ItemName'] ;
}

// Iterate through each category
foreach ( $cats_data as $category ) {
     echo '<table>';

     // echo out the table header
     echo '<tr><td>Item List for '.$category['CategoryName'].'</td></tr>' ;

     // Iterate through all the items in eaceh category
     foreach( $category['items'] as $item ) {
           echo '<tr><td>'.$item.'</td></tr>';
     }

     echo '</table>';
}

// cleanup
mysql_free_result($result);
```

it feels a lot simpler to me :)

Comment: is this correct?     `$cats_data[$row['CategoryID']['CategoryName'] = $row['categoryName'] ;
    $cats_data[$row['CategoryID']['Items'][] = $row['ItemName'] ;`

Comment: oops :) i needed to correct `$cats_data[$row['CategoryID']['CategoryName']` to `$cats_data[$row['CategoryID']]['CategoryName']`... nice catch!

Comment: I wanted your foreach alternative to work, but I couldn't get it to.