# grouping datas with same group

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to achieve to group Data by a column named 'groups'. I've been looking this post here [Categorizing mysql data into seperate html tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243264/categorizing-mysql-data-into-seperate-html-tables)

This is also applicable in my case but the same groups get separated

This is what it looked like

```
 _____________________________________
|_____________Group ZXY_______________|
|   Month       |  Bet  |  Win |Payout|
|_______________|_______|______|______|
|Name|Group|Desc|       |      |      |
|_______________|_______|______|______|
|Name|Group|Desc|       |      |      |
|_______________|_______|______|______|
|_____Total_____|_______|______|______|
 _____________________________________
|_____________Group ZXY_______________|
|   Month       |  Bet  |  Win |Payout|
|_______________|_______|______|______|
|Name|Group|Desc|       |      |      |
|_______________|_______|______|______|
|Name|Group|Desc|       |      |      |
|_______________|_______|______|______|
|_____Total_____|_______|______|______|
```

As you can see the data returned are having the same group but got separated. Must be only using 1 table in this case

Summary of my idea

Group loop
add

```
<table><th>..</th></table>
```

tags inside the variable

Data fetch loop
add

```
<tr><td>..</td></tr>
```

tags inside the variable

Here's the code

```
$sql='SELECT DISTINCT `groups` FROM `kiosk_data` WHERE `groups` IS NOT NULL ORDER BY `groups` ASC';
$grpData='';
$grpHr[]=array();

//this is the code I used to fill im th contents of the dropdown box
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
 if(!empty($row['groups']))
 {
    $selected = (isset($_GET['grp']) && $_GET['grp']==$row['groups'])?'selected="selected"':'';
    $grpData.='<option value="'.$row['groups'].'"'.$selected.'>'.$row['groups'].'</option>';
    $grpHr[]=$row['groups'];//took this opportunity to store the values of groups in grpHr[] Array
 }
}

$sql = "SELECT COALESCE(kd.`kiosk_name`,'Total') AS 'Kiosk', 
FORMAT(SUM(`casino_bets`),2) AS 'CBTotal', FORMAT(SUM(`bet_win`),2) AS 'BWTotal'
,FORMAT((`casino_bets`-`bet_win`)/`casino_bets`*100,2) AS 'Payout', groups  FROM 
`kiosk_data` kd LEFT JOIN `kiosk_status` ks ON kd.`kiosk_id`=ks.`kiosk_id` WHERE 
`kiosk_name` IS NOT NULL AND `casino_bets` IS NOT NULL AND `bet_win` IS NOT NULL";
$result = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result ->execute();


foreach ($grpHr as $key => $value) {//iterate til the last group name 
    $key = $row['groups'];//I think I need to do this before entering the fetch loop
   echo '<table><tr><td colspan="6">'.$row['groups'].'</td></tr><tr><th colspan="3">'.date("m",strtotime($row['date'])).'Month</th><th>Bet</th><th>Bet-Win</th><th>Payout %</th></tr>';
    while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
       echo '<tr><td>'.$row['Kiosk'].'</td><td>'.$row['groups'].'</td><td>'.$row['city'].'</td><td>'.$row['CBTotal'].'</td><td>'.$row['BWTotal'].'</td><td>'.$row['Payout'].'</td></tr>';
    }
}
```

Any other possible workaround for something better aside from my idea?

Comment: From how I understood your post, I thought you had a working code, but that `foreach` block looks strange to me. Is it really giving you the results you want?

Comment: Also, I had a look at the question you linked, the answer there should work if you sort your query by `groups` and check `$row['groups']` for changes at the beginning of the `while` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your second query retrieves the needed data, please try the following version of your PHP code:

```
$sql='SELECT DISTINCT `groups` FROM `kiosk_data` WHERE `groups` IS NOT NULL ORDER BY `groups` ASC';
$grpData='';
$grpHr[]=array();

//this is the code I used to fill im th contents of the dropdown box
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    if(!empty($row['groups']))
    {
        $selected = (isset($_GET['grp']) && $_GET['grp']==$row['groups'])?'selected="selected"':'';
        $grpData.='<option value="'.$row['groups'].'"'.$selected.'>'.$row['groups'].'</option>';
        $grpHr[]=$row['groups'];//took this opportunity to store the values of groups in grpHr[] Array
    }
}

$sql = "SELECT COALESCE(kd.`kiosk_name`,'Total') AS 'Kiosk', 
FORMAT(SUM(`casino_bets`),2) AS 'CBTotal', FORMAT(SUM(`bet_win`),2) AS 'BWTotal'
,FORMAT((`casino_bets`-`bet_win`)/`casino_bets`*100,2) AS 'Payout', groups  FROM 
`kiosk_data` kd LEFT JOIN `kiosk_status` ks ON kd.`kiosk_id`=ks.`kiosk_id` WHERE 
`kiosk_name` IS NOT NULL AND `casino_bets` IS NOT NULL AND `bet_win` IS NOT NULL";
$result = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result ->execute();

$grpsArr = array();    
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    if( ! isset($grpsArr[$row['groups']])) {
        $grpsArr[$row['groups']] = array();
    }
    $grpsArr[$row['groups']][] = $row;
}

foreach ($grpsArr as $grpName => $grpRowArray) {    
    echo '<table><tr><th colspan="6">'.$grpName.'</td></tr><tr><th colspan="3">'
         .date("m",strtotime($row['date']))
         .' Month</th><th>Bet</th><th>Bet-Win</th><th>Payout %</th></tr>';

    foreach($grpRowArray as $grpRow) {
        echo '<tr><td>'.$grpRow['Kiosk'].'</td><td>'.$grpRow['groups'].'</td><td>'.$grpRow['city'].'</td><td>'.$grpRow['CBTotal'].'</td><td>'.$grpRow['BWTotal'].'</td><td>'.$grpRow['Payout'].'</td></tr>';
    }

    echo '</table>';
}
```

What has been changed are the `while` / `foreach` loops. Below please find the explanation.

### `while` loop

```
$grpsArr = array();    
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    if( ! isset($grpsArr[$row['groups']])) {
        $grpsArr[$row['groups']] = array();
    }
    $grpsArr[$row['groups']][] = $row;
}
```

This loop iterates through all of the rows returned by your last query, putting the data into `$grpsArr` nested array. The section :

```
        if( ! isset($grpsArr[$row['groups']])) {
            $grpsArr[$row['groups']] = array();
        }
```

checks whether there has already been at least one row from the `$row['groups']` group throughout the iteration - if there was no such row till now, sub array is created for `$row['groups']` group name;

The line:

```
        $grpsArr[$row['groups']][] = $row;
```

adds current iteration row to the subarray of the group indicated in `$row['groups']`.

After fetching the last record from the recordset, the `$grpsArr` array should look like:

```
grpsArr = array {
                "group_1" => array {
                                    array { 
                                            "Kiosk"    => "KioskVal_1",
                                            "groups"   => "group_1",
                                            "city"     => "city_1",
                                            "CBTotal"  => 123.45
                                            "BWTotal"  => ...
                                            "Payout"   => ...
                                          } ,
                                    ( ......... ) , 
                                    array { 
                                            "Kiosk"    => "KioskVal_31",
                                            "groups"   => "group_1",
                                            "city"     => "city_11",
                                            "CBTotal"  => 123.45
                                            "BWTotal"  => ...
                                            "Payout"   => ...
                                          }
                                  }
                ( .................... ),
                "group_m" => array {
                                    array { 
                                            "Kiosk"    => "KioskVal_m",
                                            "groups"   => "group_m",
                                            "city"     => "city_m",
                                            "CBTotal"  => 123.45
                                            "BWTotal"  => ...
                                            "Payout"   => ...
                                          } ,
                                    ( .................... ) , 
                                    array { 
                                            "Kiosk"    => "KioskVal_m2",
                                            "groups"   => "group_2",
                                            "city"     => "city_mm",
                                            "CBTotal"  => 123.45
                                            "BWTotal"  => ...
                                            "Payout"   => ...
                                          }
                                  }
                }
```

### `foreach` loop

```
foreach ($grpsArr as $grpName => $grpRowArray) {  
    echo '<table><tr><th colspan="6">'.$grpName.'</td></tr><tr><th colspan="3">'
         .date("m",strtotime($row['date']))
         .' Month</th><th>Bet</th><th>Bet-Win</th><th>Payout %</th></tr>';

    foreach($grpRowArray as $grpRow) {
        echo '<tr><td>'.$grpRow['Kiosk'].'</td><td>'.$grpRow['groups'].'</td><td>'.$grpRow['city'].'</td><td>'.$grpRow['CBTotal'].'</td><td>'.$grpRow['BWTotal'].'</td><td>'.$grpRow['Payout'].'</td></tr>';
    }

    echo '</table>';
}
```

The main loop `foreach ($grpsArr as $grpName => $grpRowArray)` iterates through the first level of `$grpsArr` table, getting the group name of currently processed group and then builds HTML table start tag with header row for this specific group.

Internal loop `foreach($grpRowArray as $grpRow)` iterates over the array containing rows that belong to the the currently processed group and builds HTML table row from the obtained data.

**There is one problem**: you used in your code `.date("m",strtotime($row['date'])).` for writing the proper date/time for the group. However there is no `date` field in the results of the last query - nevertheless I've put it also in my code.

This approach should give you one HTML table for each of the groups.

I hope it helps you some way.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to solve this. The yield my expected result. Thank you. I got a question on the date part. My sample dates here dates last december 2014. But I'm seeing 01 Month here. I added the date field on the SQL query but still cant get 12 Month how could this come up with december?

Comment: Hi. I'm really glad it helped :) and thank you for accepting the answer. As for the date problem, I'll try to help best I can but I need a while to think it over - will try to respond as soon as possible. Regards.

Comment: Could you please give a query (even in the comments) where you added the date field into the query results?

Comment: It's on the part $sql = "SELECT COALESCE(kd.`kiosk_name`,'Total') AS 'Kiosk', date, ...

Comment: Actually I redone my code and achieved grouping and getting the months but when Show All is selected on the dropdown box, only 1 record is being shown you can check the code here http://jsfiddle.net/yuuto/es9mbn6j/

Comment: Hi. Sorry for such late answer. I've looked through your code and found a place where there could be a possible reason for showing only 1 row. Please look at the code in **http://jsfiddle.net/s62722w1/**. Try to substitute the whole `if` in your code with the one I've placed on the 'fiddle'. The specific place where I've added the code is marked with comments. I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi. I tried your code but still it returns only 1 row for Show All option.The row count returns the total number of records, 107 having my sample data. Maybe there's something missing or something related on the foreach ($result as $key => $val) loop?

Comment: Hi @setsuna. I'm afraid that I've mistakenly lost the code you put in jsfiddle. Please provide again the code that should be revised and I'll try to do the best I can to help. Regards.

Comment: Please try if you might the corrected version from here: http://jsfiddle.net/hd739o8p/1/ . If anything did'nt work, please write.